# Generate array of strings combined with number

Tags: shell-script, string, array

I would like to generate a local array in a shell/bash script that consists of the following elements: `JF-1998`, `JF-1999`, `JF-2000`,... , `JF-2011`. That is, a string `JF-` combined with the years from `1998` to `2000`.

I would also like to be able to do the reverse: Combine a number with a limited number of strings before that number: `JF-1998`, `RFS-1998`, `JFI-1998`.

Are there simple ways to do so?

Comment: You mean something like `arr=( JF-{1998..2011} )`?

Comment: @steeldriver: I added a new part to the question because I didn't want to cast a new one. Do you also know how to deal with combining some strings with a fixed number?

Comment: @MERose The converse of that usage: `{JF,RFS,JFI}-1998`

Comment: @steeldriver Can I put `JF,RFS,JFI` in a variable? For me it didn't work when in do `names=(JF,RFS,JFI)` and then `{$names}-1998`. Also no spaces instead of commas.

Comment: This type of variable expansion is known as *brace expansion* because you need braces: for example `echo {JF,RFS,JFI}-1998`

Comment: @steeldriver This works all very well. Now I also know the name of what I am doing. Do you want to officially answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176197/generate-array-of-strings-combined-with-number#comment291080_176197) and [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176197/generate-array-of-strings-combined-with-number#comment291326_176197) answered, bash has a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) feature that can solve your problem:

```
array1=( JF-{1998..2011} )
```

and

```
array2=( {JF,RFS,JFI}-1998} )
```

or even all together:

```
array3=( JF-{1998..2011} {JF,RFS,JFI}-1998} )
```